# Grouping XElement when generating XML from CSV

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-xml

Say I have a *.csv that is generated by 3rd party and cannot be changed.

```
ProjectName 
Fruit, Apple 
Fruit, Orange
Animal, Dog
Animal, Cat
```

Using the tutorial described in [Generate XML from CSV Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693119.aspx), I have no way but to delete the first line and obtain the following:

```
<Fruit>
  <Apple></Apple>
</Fruit>
<Fruit>
  <Orange></Orange>
</Fruit>
<Animal>
  <Dog></Dog>
</Animal>
<Animal>
  <Cat></Cat>
</Animal>
```

While I want to achieve the following, but cannot find any resource or tutorial to understand how about doing this:

```
<Project Name="ProjectName">
  <Fruit>
    <Apple></Apple>
    <Orange></Orange>
  </Fruit>
  <Animal>
    <Dog></Dog>
    <Cat></Cat>
  </Animal>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first line of the file is always the name, read that line out first, then process the rest as CSV.  After reading the rows in, group them by the appropriate column and build out the XML.

```
XDocument GetXml(string path)
{
    using (var file = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        var name = file.ReadLine();
        return new XDocument(
            new XElement("Project",
                new XAttribute("Name", name),
                from row in ReadRows(file)
                group row.Item2 by row.Item1 into g
                select new XElement(g.Key,
                    from r in g
                    select new XElement(r)
                )
            )
        );
    }
}

IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> ReadRows(TextReader file)
{
    using (var reader = new CsvReader(file, new CsvConfiguration { HasHeaderRecord = false, TrimFields = true }))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            yield return Tuple.Create(reader.GetField(0), reader.GetField(1));
    }
}
```